# paths and curves

Tags: curves

Let the path $c(t): \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be defined by $c(t)=(\sin(t)+2, 1/(\sin(t)+2))$

How can I find the location of the path at $t=n\pi$ where $n$ is any integer?

I plugged $\pi$ into $c(t)$ and I got $(0,1/2)$ for all $n$ but $(0,1/2)$ doesn't lie on the curve. I'm not sure what else to do.

Comment: @agriffin $c(n\pi) = (2,1/2)$ not $(0,1/2)$.

Comment: Ahh thank you for catching that!

Answer (score 0):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

As remarked in a comment, substituting $t=n\pi$ yields $2$ in the first coordinate, not $0$.